# Perché in Italia gli spazzini si chiamano "operatori ecologici"?

Tags: word-choice

Vivo in Italia da trentun anni e ricordo che un tempo gli spazzini, coloro che puliscono le strade e i marciapiedi, si chiamavano spazzini. Sennonché sembra che da alcuni anni a questa parte il termine *de quo* sia in disuso, essendo stato sostituito dalla locuzione "operatore ecologico".

Sapreste dirmi quali siano le origini di questa evoluzione lessicale, magari mostrando un Ngram che la evidenzi?

Non sono un nostalgico, ma, dopo tutto, non posso non osservare che le città italiane erano molto più pulite quando gli "operatori ecologici" si chiamavano "spazzini", though.

Comment: Short answer: the politically correct has won; in a few years instead of *cimitero* we'll say *casa dei diversamente vivi*.

Comment: @Matteo, great! I never thought of that, thank you.

Comment: Grande @Matteo!

Comment: (mi rendo conto solo ora che la domanda era in italiano e ho risposto in inglese... questo posto è assurdo, altera la percerzione della lingua =) )

Comment: Credo che l'ultimo paragrafetto sia da imputarsi ad un *observation bias*.

Answer (score 9):

Come già diceva Matteo nei commenti, si tratta di un'evoluzione del linguaggio verso il *politically correct*. Per cui i nani sono diversamente alti, gli spazzini sono operatori ecologici e [come diceva Bisio](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB6LtS-FNR4)

> Non sono mica calvo, ho soltanto, certo sì, la riga in mezzo che è un po' larga

È una tendenza (che personalmente non gradisco) a considerare certe condizioni come umilianti o degradanti e cercare di "addolcire la pillola" mediante l'utilizzo di tecnicismi.

Altri esempi su due piedi

- handicappato → diversamente abile/disabile
- commesso → addetto/consulente di vendita
- colf / donna delle pulizie → collaboratrice domestica

A mio modesto modo di vedere - a costo di risultare cinico - l'utilizzo di termini inutilmente pomposi o ridondanti non fa altri che rimarcare la bassa considerazione nei confronti di tali categorie.

Se dico spazzino, intendo spazzino, né più né meno. Se una persona si prende il disturbo di utilizzare il termine *operatore ecologico*, che è chiaramente meno naturale, almeno nel parlato, probabilmente questa persona giudica tale categoria come degradante e si sente in dovere di compensare utilizzando un nome tecnico.

Non dico che sia vero in ogni caso, ma personalmente la reputo una tendenza ipocrita della nostra società, che si sta manifestando nella lingua nel modo che hai evidenziato.

### EDIT

Come mi è stato fatto notare nei commenti, la risposta non contempla l'evoluzione lessicale del termine, che quindi aggiungo.

A quanto dimostra [questo Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=operatore%20ecologico&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,operatore%20ecologico;,c0)

[image]

il termine pare avere origine alla fine degli anni 70, fino a raggiungere il massimo della propria diffusione a inizio anni 90. In relazione a quanto detto sopra, pare quindi che l'utilizzo di eufemismi per riferirsi a mestieri considerati degradanti abbia origine in quegli anni.

A conferma di questa ipotesi, altri termini menzionati sopra dimostrano una tendenza molto simile. Ad esempio questo l['Ngram di ***collaboratrice domestica***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collaboratrice%20domestica&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,collaboratrice%20domestica;,c0)

[image]

E questo [quello di ***disabile***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disabile&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,disabile;,c0)

[image]

Comment: E spesso il progresso verso il politically correct rende indicibili espressioni che originariamente erano a loro volta “correct”. “Handicappato” in origine era un modo ipocr... ehm, delicato per definire chi ha qualche invalidità, paragonandolo a un cavallo da corsa che, proprio perché è migliore degli altri, è sottoposto a un handicap (un peso maggiore da portare etc.) per rendere la gara più equa. Prima di diceva forse “invalido”, che già è una litote. E prima direttamente “storpio”, “zoppo” o quel che fosse.

Comment: La cosa divertente è che "handicappato" (o "portatore di handicap") partiva già di suo come eufemismo di generazione precedente; per addetto/consulente di vendita, credo che sia un calco su "shop assistant". Edit: ecco appunto :)

Comment: Fun fact: per recuperare i termini che si usavano una cinquantina di anni fa e la diversa sensibilità al politically correct, basta andare sui vecchi tram milanesi (le mitiche "vetture carrelli", che ancora risalgono in parte agli anni '30), dove si trovano intatte targhette come "posto riservato agli invalidi e ai mutilati di guerra" e "vietato sputare". La prima oggi sarebbe un fiorire di litoti, la seconda troppo vicina alla realtà anche solo per essere pensata.

Comment: Tentato di dare -1: la risposta non tratta l'argomento della domanda (origine della locuzione), e divaga su considerazioni di carattere estraneo.

Comment: @Agos, sì forse mi sono fatto prendere un po' la mano. Ho aggiunto informazioni al post, in modo da trattare l'argomento in maniera più consona.

Answer (score 2):

Come già espresso sia nei commenti sia nella risposta di Gabriele si tratta di un'evoluzione verso il *politically correct* di termini che hanno una connotazione negativa. Nel campo delle malattie sordo diventa audioleso, cieco diventa non vedente e handicappato diventa diversamente abile mentre nell'ambito lavorativo spazzino (o anche *netturbino*) diventa operatore ecologico, bidello diventa operatore scolastico e così via.

Questa evoluzione potrebbe anche essere nata da un tentativo di riqualificazione di lavori considerati umili o degradanti ([Studi di lessicografia italiana, Volumi 17-18](http://books.google.it/books?id=fjoqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22operatore%20ecologico%22&dq=%22operatore%20ecologico%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=KtCMUqfMDIfX0QW6wYDQDA&redir_esc=y)), o di riduzione del conflitto sociale "*con strategie simboliche che mascherano l'impotenza (o la malevola indifferenza) di chi dovrebbe aiutare fattivamente queste persone a migliorarsi in salute o a guadagnare di più.*" (cit. [Principi di sociologia](http://books.google.it/books?id=Rj8dfTrr6CAC&pg=PA388&dq=%22operatore%20ecologico%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=ss6MUqHxHrL50gX3zIFQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22operatore%20ecologico%22&f=false))